Gitlab CICD issue (403 Forbidden) while pushing docker image to AWS ECR
Here .yml code to push the docker image to AWS ECR using Gitlab CICD pipeline.
I am getting unexpected status from HEAD request to https://xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/repo/manifests/6cf99375: 403 Forbidden error.
I verified the permission related to the associated user and found no issues.
I see the Gitlab runner version has been changed to Running with gitlab-runner 17.5.2 from Running with gitlab-runner 17.3.1.
Help to resolve issue.

.deploy-ecs:
  needs: [build]
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${REGION}
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "${REGION}")
    - docker pull ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAGGED}
    - echo "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}"
    - docker tag ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAGGED} "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
    - docker push "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
    - docker tag "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}"
    - docker push "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REM_REPO}:latest"
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster "${ECS_CLUSTER}" --service "${ECS_SERVICE}" --force-new-deployment --region "${REGION}"
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster "${ECS_CLUSTER}" --service "${ECS_SERVICE_SCHEDULED}" --force-new-deployment --region "${REGION}"



get-login is deprecated. Use get-login-password instead.

You must pass a token from aws ecr get-login-password to the docker login.


For example:
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ECR_REGISTRY}

I tried the approach approach but that didn't help too.

Can you check the output of aws ecr get-login-password --region ${REGION}? When you get the token you can check locally docker login. echo $THIS_TOKEN | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY

The output looked fine. We tried debugging it with DevOps's help, but it seems an issue is very specific to the new runner.
The real root cause is not yet identified.
Will update once the RCA is done.

Adding 'ecr:BatchGetImage' to the user permissions solved the issue.
With a previous runner that was not required.
